# How do I start a background job at end of request on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc

My existing web development knowledge is mostly Node. I'm exploring ASP.NET Core now and one thing that confuses me a bit is how I might start a background job at the end of the action method.

For example, in Node, I might use a function that returns immediately yet is passed a call back to log the request. The response can be sent to the user while the logging begins.

I don't want the user slowed down by the background stuff that needs to happen per request. How would I do this in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I don't know much about asp.net, but start a new Task should not block current response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an API.
It starts, shows up my IEnumerable of strings to the user.
While the page has already loaded the debugger keeps outputting "Still running here".
This works because I never await the task or ask a Result.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Still running here...");
        }
    });

    task.Start();

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. I'm not sure why I didn't see the similarities between Node promises and C# tasks. If you run them and don't await them, they run in the background. Thanks for the simple example!